# Presto Error : While launching

Tags: presto

I am getting the below error while I am launching the presto server. Kindly let me what could be the reason.

I am using presto-server-0.152.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "launcher.py", line 448, in 
>   main()
>   File "launcher.py", line 418, in main
>     node_properties = load_properties(o.node_config)
>   File "launcher.py", line 47, in load_properties
>     k, v = line.split('=', 1)
>   ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Which changes to the default configuration did you make?

Comment: I didn't make any change to configurations.

Comment: Below my configuraiotn.                                                       coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=3306
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:3306

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `etc/node.properties` file? Probably best to create a Gist https://gist.github.com/

The file seems to have a line that is missing an `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered same error before. Can you check your Python version installed on your environment?

`launcher.py` does not work with Python 3.x. So we should use Python 2.x in Presto environment.